# Custom UI for Google Games Services turn based multiplayer in Unity

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I'm working on a my first turn based game and I have a custom designed game lobby similar to letterpress (attached). I am using Google Game Play services for Unity (5.4). I can layout the UI no problem but I'm having a hard time understanding how to get the current match data so that I can put it into my own menu.

I've tried using the GPGS Plugin for Unity, I've used Prime [31], and i've searched everywhere.

If anyone knows of a good tutorial or a good method, this would be immensely helpful!

Cheers!

LetterPress Lobby Screenshot:

[image: LetterPress Lobby Screenshot]

Comment: Google has [pretty good tutorials](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer) on their site for GPGS.

Comment: You are correct. There are really good tutorials there but my issue is doing this within the realm of Unity3D. These tutorials are for native development as far as I can see. The GPGS for Unity Plugin, does not have access to all of these calls as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this was a feature that was left out originally and has since been updated. I found the thread here that has the fixes.

https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/414

Thanks!